# Added controls lost on postback

Tags: javascript, postback

I have added html controls through javascript.  However, when the page posts back, all of the added controls are lost. Is there a way to retrieve it?

Thanks,
JV

Comment: What server side technology is this related to?

Answer (score 2):

They will be,if you modify the dom with javascript the modifications will not persist through a postback, whether it is static html or dynamic server side generated you will get a new page.  You need to re add the controls every time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a couple of options. Either

1. Add a parameter to your POST to indicate that the fields were present, then if the server sees that that parameter is set, you write the fields out in your response; or
2. Do the form submission by AJAX, leaving your page undisturbed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the controls are **dynamically added** with javascript, they are supposed to vanish. If feasible, you can put them directly in your html.